# How to explain cached fibonacci algorithm complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, memoization

I'm trying to explain correctly cached fibonacci algorithm complexity. Here is the  code (https://jsfiddle.net/msthhbgy/2/):

```
function allFib(n) {
  var memo = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(i + ":" + fib(i, memo))
  }
}

function fib(n, memo) {
  if (n < 0) return 0;
  else if (n === 1) return 1;
  else if (memo[n]) return memo[n];
  memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
  return memo[n];
}

allFib(5);
```

The solution is taken from "Cracking the coding  interview" and adapted to javascript. 
So here is a "not very nice" tree of function calls

[image: function calls tree]

I was thinking like that: "The left most branch (bold one) is where the evaluation is happening" and it is definitely the number passed to the  allFib function for the first time. So the complexity is  O(n). Everything that is to the right will be taken from cache and will not require extra function calls". is it correct? also how to connect this to  the tree "theory". The  depth and the  height of the tree in this case is 4 but not 5 (close to n but not it). I want the answer to be not intuitive but more reliable.

Comment: How many times does f(k) get evaluated (for any k) when there's a cache involved?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth, it's k times

Comment: `memo[n]` is unused!

Comment: yes,  memo is unused first check if the value exists in memo if not then only calculate fib() and assign to memo.
if(memo[n]){return memo[n]}
else {memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo); return memo[n];}

Comment: Well, `O(n)` is the complexity for computing uncached/new values. the complexity to access a cached one is `O(1)`, so the final complexity of this algo has to be somewhere between `O(1)` and `O(n)`, depending on `n` and the state of your cache.

Comment: @Thomas, but to fill the  memo the function has to be called at least once  for each value. so it cannot be  smaller than  n. Or didi I get it  wrong?

Comment: Yes it can be. Your "problem" at this point is that the cache is provided to the funciton, and therefore you never know how much values are in that cache; in the case of `allFib` you always start with a new (empty) cache. But you could reuse the cache and then the second call to allFib() would "compute" the same 5 values  out of the cache. So in total computed 10 values with only 5 computations, rest came out of the cache. Usually I'd bake the cache into the fib-function and avoid that dubiety.

Comment: The case of index 0 is not defined. -- With fib[0]=0, fib[1]=1 one can calculate backwards that fib[-n]=(-1)^(n+1)*fib[n].

Comment: like this: `var fib = (memo => n => (n = Math.max(0, n|0)) in memo? memo[n]: (/*console.log("computing fib(%i)",n),*/ memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)) )([0,1]);` and then `console.log( fib(n) )` If you want to see the computations you can include the comment, then you might understand how the complexity to compute n values of this can be anywhere between 1 and n.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that really uses the cache:

```js
function Fibonacci() {
  var memo = [0, 1];

  this.callCount = 0;

  this.calc = function(n) {
    this.callCount++;
    return n <= 0 ? 0 
         : memo[n] || (memo[n] = this.calc(n - 1) + this.calc(n - 2));
  }
}

var fib = new Fibonacci();

console.log('15! = ', fib.calc(15));
console.log('calls made: ', fib.callCount);
fib.callCount = 0; // reset counter
console.log('5! = ', fib.calc(5));
console.log('calls made: ', fib.callCount);
fib.callCount = 0;
console.log('18! = ', fib.calc(18));
console.log('calls made: ', fib.callCount);
```

The number of function calls made is:

```
(n - min(i,n))*2+1
```

Where *i* is the last entry in *memo*.

This you can see as follows with the example of *n = 18* and *i = 15*:

The calls are made in this order:

```
calc(18)
calc(17)   // this.calc(n-1) with n=18
calc(16)   // this.calc(n-1) with n=17
calc(15)   // this.calc(n-1) with n=16, this can be returned from memo
calc(14)   // this.calc(n-2) with n=16, this can be returned from memo
calc(15)   // this.calc(n-2) with n=17, this can be returned from memo
calc(16)   // this.calc(n-2) with n=18, this can be returned from memo
```

The general pattern is that `this.calc(n-1)` and `this.calc(n-2)` are called just as many as times (of course), with in addition the original call `calc(n)`.

Here is an animation for when you call `fib.calc`for the first time as `fib.calc(5)`. The arrows show the calls that are made. The more to the left, the deeper the recursion. The bubbles are colored when the corresponding result is stored in *memo*:

[image: Fibonacci animation]

This evidently is *O(n)* when *i* is a given constant.

Answer (score 0):

First, check for negative `n`, and move the value to zero.

Then check if a value is cached, take the value. If not, assign the value to the cache and return the result.

For the special cases of `n === 0` or `n === 1` assign `n`.

```js
function fibonacci(number) {
    function f(n) {
        return n in cache ?
            cache[n] :
            cache[n] = n === 0 || n === 1 ? n : f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    }

    var cache = [];
    return f(number);
}

console.log(fibonacci(15));
console.log(fibonacci(5));
```

Part with predefined values in `cache`, as [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) suggested.

```js
function fibonacci(number) {
    function f(n) {
        return n in cache ?
            cache[n] :
            cache[n] = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    }

    var cache = [0, 1];
    return f(number);
}

console.log(fibonacci(15));
console.log(fibonacci(5));
```

Comment: I'd take care of the special cases by precomputing them `cache = [0,1]` then you can remove that part from the function `n === 0 || n === 1 ? n : `.